# mounting NFS folder on to nodes using a one command or shell program

Tags: shell, linux-kernel, cluster-computing

I am developing a parallel system (Bewoulf cluster) with 10 nodes. After starting the NFS Server, i ssh to each node and then mount the NFS Folder individually on each node using the below command

```
$ sudo mount 192.168.1.100:~/mpi  ~/mpi
```

ssh to each node and running the command, is a bit time consuming

Is there any other way to run one command or shell script; so that the "mount command" which will automatically executed on each nodes and mount the shared folder?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach would be to use ssh on each node.

```
for host in $(cat hosts); do
  ssh control@$host sudo mount 192.168.1.100:~/mpi  ~/mpi
done
```

You can create a password-less key and on the clients protect with a command entry in the authorized_keys file

```
command="sudo mount 192.168.1.100:~/mpi  ~/mpi",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like [pdsh](https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/) and generate password-less keys to access the compute nodes. Once you have the keys deployed you can mount all the nodes with just one command:

```
pdsh -w ^hosts_file sudo mount 192.168.1.100:~/mpi  ~/mpi
```

You can find more examples of how to use pdsh in the pdsh [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/wiki/UsingPDSH)